# Handle accessibility for UITableViewCell with multiple labels and switch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, uiswitch

I've got a UITableViewCell with two labels (title and description) and a switch (UISwitch) next to it. I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize the cell for visually impaired people.

[image: Cell picture with two labels and switch]
At the moment I've set `isAccessibilityElement` to `false` on the cell, and set the value to `true` for the two labels as well as the UISwitch.

Furthermore each label has the given text as accessibilityLabel. The switch has the text from the title label as the `accessibilityLabel`:

[image: Accessibility inspector from UISwitch]

Do you think this is a good approach for helping visually impaired people? I'm looking forward to further opinions on this topic, as I didn't found any other apps using a similar layout.

Thanks

Comment: For me your question is not clear. What is the problem?

Comment: just looking for further ideas on how to implement the best experience for visually impaired people

Comment: Then you are not at right place. StackOverflow is only for programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

According to the content of your title and description, an appropriate solution could consist in gathering the title, the label and the switch control into a unique `UIAccessibleElement` so as to reduce the selections to be done to get information and/or to perform actions.

Get [code snippets](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#grouping-elements) for this implementation (Objc or swift) and take a look at this detailed [WWDC video](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html) inside which the question '[How to gather several elements into a single one ?](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/215/?time=1910)' should provide additional information.